# Typo3 use realurl to mask tx_news_pi1 parameter in URL

Tags: php, typo3, realurl, tx-news

I am pretty new to typo3. The Website is all set up now i want to use realurl to make some human readable URLS.

Out of the boy it works pretty well. But not for my news sites.

> http://myDomain/news-events/news/Name-of-the-Article/?tx_news_pi1%5Bday%5D=19&tx_news_pi1%5Bmonth%5D=7&tx_news_pi1%5Byear%5D=2017&cHash=6af067caeb037b4de744f6b9e07b73e8

Please help me to get rid of the last Parameters. 
to get something like:

> http://myDomain/news-events/news/Name-of-the-Article/

Here is my realurl_conf

[ See Update]

Thank you all for your time =)

Update:

So i worked my way through the manual.
I copied from them and inserted my IDs and Stuff
this is my new Configuration [ Deleted the first one ]

```
<?php

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['addRootLineFields'] .= ',tx_realurl_pathsegment';

// Adjust to your needs
$domain = 'http://mydomain.de';
$rootPageUid = 1;
#$rssFeedPageType = 9818; // pageType of your RSS feed page

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'][$domain] = array(
    'pagePath' => array(
            'type' => 'user',
            'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
            'languageGetVar' => 'L',
            'expireDays' => '3',
            'rootpage_id' => $rootPageUid,
            'firstHitPathCache' => 1
    ),
    'init' => array(
            'enableCHashCache' => TRUE,
            'respectSimulateStaticURLs' => 0,
            'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile,redirect',
            'adminJumpToBackend' => TRUE,
            'enableUrlDecodeCache' => TRUE,
            'enableUrlEncodeCache' => TRUE,
            'emptyUrlReturnValue' => '/',
    ),
    'fileName' => array(
            'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 0,
            'acceptHTMLsuffix' => 1,
            'index' => array(
#                        'feed.rss' => array(
#                                'keyValues' => array(
#                                       'type' => $rssFeedPageType,
#                               )
#                        )
            )
    ),
    'preVars' => array(
            array(
                    'GETvar' => 'L',
                    'valueMap' => array(
#                                'en' => '1',
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
            array(
                    'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                            'nc' => 1,
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
    ),
    'fixedPostVars' => array(
            'newsDetailConfiguration' => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                        'detail' => '',
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                        'News' => '',
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
                    'lookUpTable' => array(
                        'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                        'alias_field' => "CONCAT(uid, '-', IF(path_segment!='',path_segment,title))",
                        /** OR ***************/
                        'alias_field' => 'IF(path_segment!="",path_segment,title)',
                        /** OR ***************/
                        'alias_field' => "CONCAT(uid, '-', title)",

                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                        'useUniqueCache' => 1, # 1?
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                            'strtolower' => 1,
                            'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                        ),
                        'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                        'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                        'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                        'expireDays' => 180,

                    ),
                    #Depends ?  
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[day]',
                        'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[month]',
                        'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[year]',
                        'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                    ),
                ),
                'newsCategoryConfiguration' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][categories]',
                        'lookUpTable' => array(
                            'table' => 'sys_category',
                            'id_field' => 'uid',
                            'alias_field' => 'title',
                            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                            'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                                'strtolower' => 1,
                                'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                'newsTagConfiguration' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][tags]',
                        'lookUpTable' => array(
                            'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_tag',
                            'id_field' => 'uid',
                            'alias_field' => 'title',
                            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                            'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                                'strtolower' => 1,
                                'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                ),
                #TODO: ID-News Seite Finden
                #'145' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',
                #'147' => 'newsDetailConfiguration', // For additional detail pages, add their uid as well
                #'134' => 'newsDetailConfiguration', // For additional detail pages, add their uid as well
                '148' => 'newsDetailConfiguration', // For additional detail pages, add their uid as well
                '149' => 'newsDetailConfiguration', // For additional detail pages, add their uid as well
                #'71' => 'newsTagConfiguration',
                #'72' => 'newsCategoryConfiguration',
        ),
        'postVarSets' => array(
            '_DEFAULT' => array(
                'controller' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
                        'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
                        'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                    )
                ),

                'dateFilter' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][year]',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][month]',
                    ),
                ),
                'page' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[@widget_0][currentPage]',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

But still there are the 
tx_news_pi1[day], tx_news_pi1[month], tx_news_pi1[year] and cHash
Parameters in the URL. 
Please Help me to get rid of them.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of news https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Realurl/Index.html

Comment: yes, i found that document earlier but i don't quite get it I guess.
I mean where do I put that Data, there are so many  arrays.

Comment: why do you have `tx_realurl_pathsegment` added to your rootline fields? (second line)

Comment: Its in the Advanced Example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats my configuration:

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']=array (
    '_DEFAULT' => array (
        'init' => array (
            'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile,redirect',
             'emptyUrlReturnValue' => '/',
        ),
        'pagePath' => array (
            'rootpage_id' => '2',
        ),
        'fileName' => array (
            'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => 0,
            'acceptHTMLsuffix' => 1,
            'index' => array (
                'print' => array (
                    'keyValues' => array (
                        'type' => 98,
                     ),
                 ),
             ),
        ),
        'preVars' => array(
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'L',
                'valueMap' => array(
                    'en' => '1',
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
                'valueMap' => array(
                    'nc' => 1,
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),
        ),
        'fixedPostVars' => array(
            // config for single/detail news: 
            'newsDetailConfiguration' => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                        'detail' => '',
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                        'News' => '',
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
                    'lookUpTable' => array(
                        'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                        'alias_field' => 'concat(uid,\'_\',title)',
                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                            'strtolower' => 1,
                            'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                        ),
                        'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                        'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                        'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                        'autoUpdate' => 1,
                        'expireDays' => 180,
                    )
                )
            ),
            // config for category selection: 
            'newsCategoryConfiguration' => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][categories]',
                    'lookUpTable' => array(
                        'table' => 'sys_category',
                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                        'alias_field' => 'title',
                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                            'strtolower' => 1,
                            'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            // configuration for tag selection:
            'newsTagConfiguration' => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][tags]',
                    'lookUpTable' => array(
                        'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_tag',
                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                        'alias_field' => 'title',
                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                            'strtolower' => 1,
                            'spaceCharacter' => '-'
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            // add your page uids where you have detail view of news:
            '70' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',
            //'701' => 'newsDetailConfiguration', // For additional detail pages, add their uid as well
            /connect page uid for further views: tag-selection, category-selection"
            '71' => 'newsTagConfiguration',
            '72' => 'newsCategoryConfiguration',
        ),
        'postVarSets' => array(
            '_DEFAULT' => array(
                'controller' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
                        'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
                        'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                    )
                ),

                'dateFilter' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][year]',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][month]',
                    ),
                ),
                'page' => array(
                    array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[@widget_0][currentPage]',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

look for the right insertion in the array. For that have a clean indention!

Comment: tried yours. And got it working but the Parameters where still there.

Comment: the old urls are still known and in cache. so if you want all urls be clean you need to clear all caches and all generated urls. aside from usual cache clearing you have to use the "Flash all data (harmful!)" Button in the realurl BE module.

Answer (score 0):

The already mentioned link is quite useful and contains detailed info:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Realurl/Index.html

There are 3 ways explained there:

1. a basic one which still shows action and controller name as an URL path segment
2. an advanced example (the one Bernd Wilke is using in his sample as well)
3. a TypoScript solution to avoid controller and action name in URL

Option 2 can only be used if you show your detail news on a dedicated pages (separate page for list and detail view) as you configure a preset for a controller and action name for a special page (uid) - your news detail view.

Option 3 basically does the same as Option 2, but on a TypoScript level and it can be used in a case where list and detail view is on one single page.
Both options can / should be used in combination with the setting *skipControllerAndAction = 1*.

In case you want to use the basic setup. The postVarSets is on the same level as *fixedPortsVars* or *preVars*

Additional hint:
Do you use any other language than DE or EN as your default language? If so your default language has sys language uid of 0 and thus all good.
The default language usually has sys language uid of 0. If you do not need a default language path segment, you leave it out in our real url config thus it gets bypassed.
More info on language setup: https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Notes-for-Integrators#configuring-languages

RealUrl Doc:
https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki

Comment: Thank you for explaining the examples. I took the 2. one as well and inserted the the specific things [News-Detail UID, $Domain etc.]
The language hint is nice but i dont got any language right now. 
The _skipControllerAndAction = 1_ is in my setup.ts